# YouTube link to Iframe?

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube

I want a function for WordPress that will take a YouTube id from a link and automatically turn it into an `iframe` embed code inside custom field `video_url`.

```
video_url = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqV4uGLQ2L0
```

Sometimes OEmbed doesn't work on my WordPress site, so I am looking for this solution.

This:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqV4uGLQ2L0
```

Should automatically be wrapped this way:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UqV4uGLQ2L0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: ,do you want to open video in same window right?

Comment: Not to open anywhere, I just need php code that turns custom field value video_url where is link into full iframe inside single.php with function, so I don't actually change single.php values.

Comment: can you please give me example.

Comment: I create post with custom field value video_url = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqV4uGLQ2L0, now on front end in post, where I call custom field, I want it to turn inside iframe, and by functions.php.

Comment: you want to create a link that or store link

Comment: function youtubeLinkCreator($uTubeID)
{
  
  $newurl="http://www.youtube.com/v/"+$uTubeID;
  return $newurl;
}

Comment: ok get it now.You have to load url

Answer (score 0):

Use below function, It will return youtube embed link.

Pass your youtube url into function and then it will return embed code link.

**in functions.php**

```
function parseVideos($videoString = null)
{   
    if (strpos($videoString, 'youtube.com/embed') !== FALSE) 
    {
        return $videoString;
    }
    if (strpos($videoString, 'iframe') !== FALSE) 
    {
        // retrieve the video url
        $anchorRegex = '/src="(.*)?"/isU';
        $results = array();
        if (preg_match($anchorRegex, $video, $results)) 
        {
            $link = trim($results[1]);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        // we already have a url
        $link = $videoString;
    }    

    if (strpos($link, 'youtube.com') !== FALSE) { 

        preg_match(
        '/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/',
        $link,
        $matches
        );  
        //the ID of the YouTube URL: x6qe_kVaBpg
        $id = $matches[1];
        return '//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$id;
    }
    else if (strpos($link, 'youtu.be') !== FALSE) { 
        preg_match(
        '/youtu.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\??/i',
        $link,
        $matches
        );  
        $id = $matches[1];
        return '//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$id;
    }
    else if (strpos($link, 'player.vimeo.com') !== FALSE) {
        // works on:
        // http://player.vimeo.com/video/37985580?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0
        $videoIdRegex = '/player.vimeo.com\/video\/([0-9]+)\??/i';
        preg_match($videoIdRegex, $link, $matches);
        $id = $matches[1];  
        return '//player.vimeo.com/video/'.$id;
    }
    else if (strpos($link, 'vimeo.com') !== FALSE) { 
        //extract the ID
        preg_match(
                '/\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/',
                $link,
                $matches
            );

        //the ID of the Vimeo URL: 71673549 
        $id = $matches[2];  
        return '//player.vimeo.com/video/'.$id;
    }
    return $videoString;
    // return data

}
```

Comment: It does not work. Is it maybe cause my video link is inside custom field video_url?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** retrieve value of custom_field called video url :

```
$unescpaed_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video_url', true );
```

**Step 2:** escape url value after retrieval:

```
if ( $unescpaed_url) {
    // Returns an empty string for invalid URLs
    $url = esc_url( 'http://' . $unescpaed_url );

    if ( '' !== $url ) {
        $display = esc_html( $unescpaed_url );

        print "<a href='$url' target='_blank'>$display</a>";
    }
}
```